# IBM watson visual recognition services _visualRecognition.Classify() is not returning proper result for Custom classes

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am developing VR tool in .NET framework using IBM watson visual recognition service. _visualRecognition. Classify () method was working fine for the custom classifiers before a week. Now I am running the same code but it's not working properly, it's not classifying any images with respect to created custom classes. It's working as default classify method even after passing classifierID's and Owner Id's. It's work as default classify method

Code:

```
var result = _visualRecognition.Classify(imageByte, imagePath, "image/jpg", Urls, Classifiers, Owners, 0.8f, "en");
```

Before same code returning below result. Please refer below image:

[Result running same code before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnTT4.png)

Result "One" class in Custom classifiers.

But now same code is returning different result:

[Same image, but returning different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1h78.png)

Comment: You haven't provided a clear statement of the problem. If you've changed the code, you should say so and show the code. If you are working with different data than before, state that.

Comment: var result = _visualRecognition.Classify(imageByte, imagePath, "image/jpg", Urls, Classifiers, Owners, 0.8f, "en");, This is my code. It was classifying image as per our created custom classifier. I am running the same code after a week but it's not giving right result.

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question. Did you have both classifications before? Have you added new training data? What's the confidence level of the before and after? What's the confidence level of the one not showing before/after?  Do you get the same results if you put your classifier in a different domain?

Comment: Ya I trained and last week it's working fine but now I am running the same code, not getting correct result ( I am working on .NET SDK)

Answer (score 2):

We updated the service last Monday and a slight change in how certain options took precedence caused a problem with users of the node SDK. If you update your node SDK from github it should resolve the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I am working on .NET SDK. Last week it's working fine. Now I am not getting correct result for same code.

Comment: Your example does not show what value you assigned to `Owners` or `Classifiers` - but you should make sure `Owners` does not contain `IBM` if you want to use only your custom classifiers, which I think is your intent since you have classifier_ids there.  `Classifiers` should list the custom classifier_ids you want to use.

Comment: Owners values is optional right ? before i was running "_visualRecognition.Classify(imageByte, imagePath, "image/jpg", Urls, ClassifiersIds);"  where classifieresIds contains all customClassifier id's. But now same code is not giving correct answer and It's not classifying image with respect custom classifiers

Comment: Yes, `owners` is optional.  You would need to show more of your code, including the values you have given each variable before calling `Classify` to tell what is going on.

Comment: Please refer below links for code and variable data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cauowL0BBkawuXO0LhDtEH8EqBBLVYg3/view?usp=sharing            https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JQh6bTJSJ_0JnWEZtTykEA7vflDuZ3xR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure, here is the piece of code where i call the classify

var classifierResult = _visualRecognition.Classify(image, fileName, "image/jpeg", classifierIDs: _classifierId, threshold: 0.1f);

The classifier id is:

private readonly string[] _classifierId = { "M*********96" };

When I retrieve the classifiers with _visualRecognition.GetClassifiersBrief(); My classifier is successfully retrieved.

Comment: It seems your code example is different in your last comment and in the google drive links from earlier.  The google drive links do not appear to set the threshold, which means 0.5 is used by default.  In your final comment it appears you try to set it to 0.1, which is very likely to show some results, but if you want to see _all_ the results from a custom classifier, you should set the threshold parameter to 0.  Also, you should not send a URLs parameter with a value of null.  You are sending the image bytes in the request.